# How to show the name of the case handler in the queue

Tags: case

I need to get the user who open/handles the case. After the case is assigned to a queue, there are different users inside it, right? So how will I know or how do i get the user who edits/manages the case if the name in the case owner is the queue name? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If a user updates the case then they will be recorded as the last updated person for the record. If cases need to be managed by individuals then you could have them assigned ownership from the queue if they update it.

Comment: is there any way to get the user who opened the case? without editing it?

Comment: There is a way to get it but it is only really possible to do a very simple view without either a lot of work or a third party app. Will put up a simple answer soon.

Comment: alternative solution is for user to take ownership and then assign a case team to the case if others need to see status

Comment: @cropredy what i need is to get the exact user (ex. user name) in the queue who opened the case. is that possible?